# Trying to implement a digital LPF

Tags: lowpass-filter, digital-filters

So I took this digital LPF from some website:

[image]

And tried implement it first in MatLab to see how it goes, here's the code used:

```
x=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
y=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

t = linspace(0,1,100);
%a = sin(2*pi*0.1*t)
%plot(t,a)


yy = zeros(1, 100);

for c= 1:100
x(1) = sin(2*pi*1000*t(c));
y(1) = ((1.*x(1)+2.*x(2)+ 1.*x(3)) + 1.789.*y(2) -0.948.*y(3))./4.841;
yy(c) = y(1);

  for i = 1:10
    x(i+1) = x(i); % store xi
    y(i+1) = y(i); % store yi
  end
end

plot(t,yy)
```

Got this for a sine with 100Hz frequency :

[image]

Sine with 1000Hz frequency:

[image]

It's just not working as intended. What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

New sampling frequency of 1000Hz

[image]

New code used:

```
x=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
y=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

t = linspace(0,1,1000);
%a = sin(2*pi*0.1*t)
%plot(t,a)

yy = zeros(1, 1000);

for c= 1:1000
x(1) = sin(2*pi*10*t(c));
y(1) = ((1.*x(1)+2.*x(2)+ 1.*x(3)) + 503.273.*y(2) -231.158.*y(3))./276.115;
yy(c) = y(1);

  for i = 1:10
    x(i+1) = x(i); % store xi
    y(i+1) = y(i); % store yi
  end
end

plot(t,yy)
```

The signal appears to be already attenuated at a frequency if 10Hz, how is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Much better! Thank-you.

Comment: already asked and partially answered here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/646012/trying-to-implement-a-digital-lpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The signal appears to be already attenuated at a frequency if 10Hz, how is that possible?

Well, if the input signal is correct (which it is) and the filter coefficients are correct (which they are) and the output is wrong (which it is), the only possibility is that your filter code is wrong (which it is).

This is good opportunity to hone your debugging skills.

1. Start with the most simple input signal and the most simple filter (unit impuls for both). Check the results.
2. Slowly increase the complexity of the input signal and the filter but always use examples that you can simply do by hand as well.
3. Continue until it breaks, i.e. where the answer from your code is different from the answer you have calculated manually  or have from a known good reference implementation.
4. Then single step through your code and determine where it breaks.
5. Putting comments in your code liberally is also a VERY good idea. Your code has none.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your code performs filtering correctly.</strike>

One problem is your input signal frequencies ($f_1 = 100\,\text{Hz}$ and $f_2 = 1000\,\text{Hz}$) are too high with regards to your sampling frequency ($f_s = 100\,\text{Hz}$), violating [Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), and introducing aliased frequencies ($f_1$ aliases to $1\,\text{Hz}$ and $f_2$ aliases to $10\,\text{Hz}$).

To see your filter in action, set $f_1 = 10\,\text{Hz}$ and $f_2 = 30\,\text{Hz}$, which are $\leq f_s/2$:

```
x(1) = sin(2*pi*10*t(c) % LPF will pass this signal
x(1) = sin(2*pi*30*t(c)) % LPF will attenuate this signal
```

---

**EDIT**

Another problem is, as @Hilmar mentioned in [his answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85732/63763), that there **is** a bug in your code **with the past input and past output storing routine** (your inner loop is not doing what you think it's doing).

Comment: Things seem to work fine if i do as you say. In the new post edit i just made i changed the sampling frequency to 1000Hz, the signal seems to be attenuated already at 10Hz?

Comment: Sorry, the code does NOT work correctly.

Comment: @Scipio Hilmar is correct. There is indeed a bug in your filtering routine. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Yeah thanks to you guys i already found out, it should be i = 10:-1:1. Now everything works and intended.